# iOS app missing screenshot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Since iOS 6 came out and Apple is requiring screenshots for any apps you update, I'm having problems with app submission!

What if I DO NOT want to have my app support the iPhone 5's big screen yet?

Can I still submit my app without the screen shots? Cause apple is sending me messages regarding these missing screenshots!
Thank you!

Comment: The emails are only saying that you should update your app with new screen shots. They're not saying you have to.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had a similar problem when submitting an update that did not include support for the iPhone 5.  I saw a warning in Xcode that said I was missing "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image.  When I clicked on the warning in Xcode, I was given an option to add a default launch image and I added the default image.  Everything worked fine when I created an archive and validated the file in Xcode, however, I eventually got an email from the iTunes store saying "The status for the following app has changed to Missing Screenshot."  After tying several things, I eventually figured out that I could remove the "Default-568h@2x.png" file from my project and resubmit it without the requirement to add the new screenshots for the iPhone 5. I think the presence of the "Default-568h@2x.png" triggers the need to have iPhone 5 screenshots.

To summarize, the problem I had was caused by adding the "Default-568h@2x.png" file to the project without adding screenshots to support the iPhone 5 display.  When I removed the .png file, validated and resubmitted my app, I was able to successfully submit my app without the screenshots.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Any idea how to get rid of the compiler warning of a missing launch image?

Comment: #Marplesoft I am not sure how to get rid of the compiler warning.  I think that persisted until I eventually added iPhone 5 support to my app.  On another note, Apple announced on 3/21 that as of 5/1/2013 it will require iPhone 5 support so you may want to consider going ahead and adding support now.  Here is a link https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013b.

Comment: the answer will no more work after `May 1 2013` as you cannot skip to have the app that does not support iPhone5 resolution.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem while uploading the App to Appstore. Status changed to "Missing Screenshots(1)".

I added a new screenshot of size 1136x640 under "4 inches retina display screenshots" and the status changed to "Waiting for review" immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The image that apple is asking for is a iTunes image, not an app image. They're looking for a 1024x1024 image so that Mac Retina displays can use that image. Previous the iTunes artwork was 512x512 which you no longer need.

Comment: So when my app status is "Missing Screensot (1)" I'm missing an app image? Where do I put submit this image? Thanks! :)

Comment: @iLive Edit the **Version Information** and scroll to the bottom you'll want to update the *Large App Icon*

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple:

1. The only way to set your app to support iPhone 5 screen is to add launch image for the 4" retina display on your target summary (You can always delete it and you would be back to 3.5" app). If you won't add this launch screen your app would run on 3.5" in the center of iPhone 5 screen (the rest of the screen would be black) and as it used to on older iPhones.
2. If you submit an app without this launch screen (4") Apple won't ask you for screenshots for iPhone 5.
3. If you submit an app with the 4" launch screen the app would go to "missing screenshots" state and won't even be reviewed until you add screenshots for 4" display.

Pay attention that Apple soon would stop getting updates of apps that don't support iPhone 5 screen (according to press), So, It is highly recommended to put that on your tasks. Moreover, It is really ugly to run on 3.5" when you have 4".

Hope this explains a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into same issue, however my problem was that I forgot to upload the iPad screenshot. Not having an actual iPad I just set devices to iPad retina via Xcode, clicked run, then clicked File -> Save Screen Shot. Then submitted via iTunes: view details -> Click edit in Metadata and Uploads" section -> Choose file under iPad screenshots.

After uploading iPad screen shot, my status went instantly into "under review".