# Status "Missing Screenshot [1]" after uploading app to appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, screenshot

Yesterday I uploaded my first app to the Apple Appstore. The status currently is "Missing Screenshot [1]" with clicking on [1] leading to popup saying "Missing Localized Screenshots English". As far as I know the locale is English, at least intended to be. The page in iTunesConnect contains four screen shots under the only heading present: "3.5-Inch Retina Display Screenshots" and there is no room for other screenshots. Although I must say that I changed status from universal app to iPhone app. I have no idea what to do. I did upload the screen shots via iTunes, there were none included when I uploaded the binaries to the appstore. Should I have had these screen shots included in the Organizer as well? In the status history it says "Upload received" and two minutes later "Missing screenshot", leading me to think that these screenshots should have been included in the binary. If so, how should I add the screenshots? I did read something about Apple requiring to add screenshot for iPhone5, but I have no idea where to add these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem earlier - nothing to do with the locale. Found solution here:

[iOS app missing screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681702/ios-app-missing-screenshot)

Effectively if you let Xcode input an image for iPhone5 to be-rid of a warning - Apple expects you to put in iPhone5 Screenshots.

Solve by deleting this image (Default-568h@2x.png) and re-uploading binary or adding iPhone5 screenshots inside iTunesConnect.

Additionally - strange you shouldn't be able to see where to put the screenshots for iPhone5.
Here's the path:
iTunesConnect/Manage Your Apps/*your app*/view details/ then click the edit button by the "meta data and uploads" / scroll down and it should be there: "4 inch retina screen shots"

Comment: I just discovered myself that in iTunes there is a button "Metadata and Uploads" and then I could upload screenies for iPhone5 and iPad. Exactly as you say, Okami. Thanks. Problem probably solved.

Comment: A few minutes later status now says: "Waiting For Review", so it should be okay now. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

If you've had the "missing localized screenshot" error see if the below helps as we had a similar issue with an App that was submitted.

1. If you have a universal app binary, make sure you have submitted iPhone and iPad screenshots.
2. If you binary works for iPhone 4, then you must include the screens for the iPhone 4 too.
3. If you are applying for an app to be made available in different regions, then you need to click on the "choose another language" and from the drop-down choose the region and you should be able to see that Apple pre-populates the images/screenshots for you but you will need to add the keywords and the description.