# Submit iPhone app only for 3.5 inch screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I already have deleted the 4" default black screen from my project, I uploaded my binary, and it still says my app supports the 4" screen. None of my views are set to the 4" screen. So is there a hidden section or something that im missing? Everything works perfect except it wants me to upload a screen shot for the 4" screen shot.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to target the most devices possible?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itunesconnect.com is not "detecting" that you app wants to use the 4" screen and there is not a setting to submit for only 3.5" screens.  Now that the iPhone 5 is out, Apple simply wants everyone to submit a screenshots for the 4" screen.  It is a little bit of a pain, but there is no way around it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. So if i add a screen shot for the 4" screen, ill be able to upload my app, Right? But when i go on the simulator for the 4" screen, my images are all stretched out. if the user downloads the app with 4" phone, will it automatically give them the black bars on the top and bottom of the app? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AlexMoyer See the following answer that may help you.  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12683724/1203475]  You do not have to upload 4" screenshots if you do not include a "Default-568h@2x.png"

Answer (score 0):

Every project has to support 3.5-Inch and 4-Inch.

The black screen is just set for splash screen being displayed when the app starts.

In this case, your app has no splash image on 4-Inch devices.